# Limit search to specific subfolder in Glob Python

Tags: python, path, glob

Currently, I am using `glob` to comb nested folder to extract folder with a file `raw.txt` as below.

```
from glob import glob

droot='/mnt/d/mdir/hus/'
apath=glob(f"{droot}/*/*/*/raw.txt")
```

and `apath` output is as below

```
['/mnt/d/mdir/hus/MOI/abc_123/t1/raw.txt',
'/mnt/d/mdir/hus/MOI/abc_123 /t3/raw.txt',
'/mnt/d/mdir/hus/MOI/Khai_b720 /t1/raw.txt',
'/mnt/d/mdir/hus/MOI/Khai_b720/t3/raw.txt',
'/mnt/d/mdir/hus/MOI/art_b730430/t1/raw.txt',
'/mnt/d/mdir/hus/MOI/art_b730430/t2/raw.txt']
```

Say, for example, I am to limit the search to only a list of subfolder

`Khai_b720` and `art_b730430`

Is there is a way we set this directly in the `glob` argument.

Maybe something like

```
apath=glob(f"{droot}/*/{Khai_b720,art_b730430}/*/raw.txt")
```

Such that the expected output should be

```
['/mnt/d/mdir/hus/MOI/Khai_b720 /t1/raw.txt',
'/mnt/d/mdir/hus/MOI/Khai_b720/t3/raw.txt',
'/mnt/d/mdir/hus/MOI/art_b730430/t1/raw.txt',
'/mnt/d/mdir/hus/MOI/art_b730430/t2/raw.txt']
```

Currently, I rely on the following

```
k=['Khai_b720','art_b730430']
pathb=[x for x in s if any(kk in x for kk in k) ]
```

Comment: Use a separate glob for each subfolder. There's no way to do this in one glob.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I don't think it's possible with glob, glob only supports *, ? and [ab] [a-z] [!a] like stuff. There was a PR to add such functionality but I don't think it was added and is going to be https://bugs.python.org/issue9584

You could try to implement it with [] notation but it will also match many other file names you don't want. An alternative would be filtering using a regex on your glob, like

```
[x for x in glob(f"{droot}/*/*/*/raw.txt") if re.match(f'^{droot}/[^/]+/(Khai_b720|art_b730430)/.*$', x)]
```

here, I match everything which starts with droot (^ means beginning of string) then has a slash then at least one non slash character and all if there are many, then a slash, then one dir name or the other, then anything (.*) and then end of line with $